# Are level 1 and level 2 residuals in a mixed effects model always normally distributed?

Tags: modeling, linear-model, random-effects-model, mixed-model

Take this mixed effects model:

$y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{ij} + \mu_{j} + \epsilon_{ij}$

The level 2 residuals are $\mu_{j}$ and the level 1 residuals are $\epsilon_{ij}$. As I understand the level 1 and level 2 should be each be normally distributed in this model.

My question: are the level 1 and level 2 residuals always normally distributed in a mixed effects model? If yes, how does the model ensure the level 1 and level 2 residuals are always normally distributed?

Answer (score 5):

Typically in linear regression, normally distributed errors are necessary for hypothesis testing. For MLE it is a key assumption; non-normal errors will lead to incorrect standard errors, though the point estimates will be consistent and unbiased (asymptotically). But it is an assumption you must test, I do not believe the algorithms "force" normality on the errors.

This paper by [Maas and Hox](http://joophox.net/publist/csda04.pdf) goes into what happens when your data violate that assumption.  Their general conclusion is that non-normal 2nd level errors "only causes problems when one is interested in the significance or in the confidence intervals of the variance terms at the second level."

Comment: Do level 2 residuals need to be normally distributed around each level 1 residual? Let's say there are 500 level 1 residuals (therefore 500 groups in a random variable). What happens if a proportion of level 2 residuals are normally distributed for example 100/500?

Comment: I've always thought the assumption is they are normally distributed across the entire sample - you would graph that or do some other test to assess it. I believe the hypothesis testing is for the coefficients and random effects across all groups, not the group-specific effects. I suppose you could assess to see if the individual residuals are normal within each group, but I don't know if that is necessary.